# Manage multiple VMware Server installations through one web interface

Tags: vmware-server

I have 5 physical machines running VMware Server 2.  Each one runs 6-10 VMs.  I sometimes forget which host machine is running a particular VM so I often find myself logging into each host trying to find the VM I'm looking for.  I've noticed that the Inventory section of the web interface for VMware, it lists the currently logged into host machine and the VMs beneath it.  Is there a way to make an instance of VMware Server aware of other servers so that it lists more than just it's own server in the inventory?  The UI seems to be designed for this capability but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: You can document what VMs are on each host for starters...

Comment: I tried that but they get moved around by coworkers that aren't as diligent about documenting as I am.  Regardless, this isn't really about knowing which VMs are where, rather it is about centrally managing all of them from one place.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the toy/free product, the feature you're looking for is in their chargeable product vSphere - you don't get the goodies for nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I thought vSphere was all about high/continuous availability?  I don't need any of that.  All of the VMs that I have are simply for testing so uptime/reliability is really a non issue.  I was just hoping for a more convenient way to restarting/configuring a VM from time to time.

Comment: The way it gives you HA etc is via visibility of multiple hosts.